# How can I access alphanumeric values in Dialog Flow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a requirement where the user says “ location is ECC86623”, where ECC86 623 is the room number in a building. Is it possible that I can provide an alphanumeric string for intents? Also, I want to take value L1005 also. Or tell me about any method of setting custom values which take every value in the same format like flight number. Is there any way to set the condition like validation or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're meaning to ask about is training phrases as well as extracting and validating the entities from those training phrases (such as location in this case). You can see [Dialogflow's Regex sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-regex-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) to get a better idea of how this will look in your fulfillment logic.